# create custom list view in android

Tags: android

i want to set custom layout for list view in android studio

i add a list view in activity_main.xml file

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and create a layout file with name row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/icon"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium"
            android:id="@+id/text1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="small"
            android:id="@+id/text2"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and MainActivity.java file include :

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ListView list;
String [] titles;
String [] description;
int[]imgs = {R.drawable.fb,R.drawable.chat,R.drawable.gplus,R.drawable.instagram};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Resources res = getResources();

    titles = res.getStringArray(R.array.titles);
    description = res.getStringArray(R.array.description);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this,titles,imgs,description);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
    Context context;
    int[] imgs;
    String[] myTitles;
    String[] myDescription;

    MyAdapter (Context c , String[] titles , int[] imgs , String[]Description){
        super(c,R.layout.row,R.id.text1,titles);
        this.context = c;
        this.imgs = imgs;
        this.myDescription = description;
        this.myTitles = titles;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position , View convertView , ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row,null,true);
        ImageView images = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView myTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        TextView myDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
        images.setImageResource(imgs[position]);
        myTitle.setText(titles[position]);
        myDescription.setText(description[position]);
        return row;
    }
}
```

}

when i run the application , display : Unfortunately , application has stopped.

how  to resolve this problem ?

error log :

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                   at com.example.nik.myapplication.MainActivity$MyAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:57)
                                                                                   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2207)
                                                                                   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1845)
                                                                                   at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
                                                                                   at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:739)
                                                                                   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1661)
                                                                                   at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2037)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14118)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4474)
                                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:985)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14118)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4474)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14118)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4474)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:435)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14118)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4474)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14118)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4474)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1670)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1528)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1441)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14118)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4474)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14118)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4474)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2183)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1947)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4879)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5341)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:929)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please show an error log

Comment: can't know for sure no error log posted but just a maybe: instead of  ImageView images = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon); you should try to find it from ROW view like this:  ImageView images = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

Comment: error log added...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your answer:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position , View convertView , ViewGroup parent){
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row,null,true);
    ImageView images = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView myTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    TextView myDescription = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text2);
    images.setImageResource(imgs[position]);
    myTitle.setText(titles[position]);
    myDescription.setText(description[position]);
    return row;
}
```

And here is why that's your answer:

You were having a null pointer exception because you were calling findViewById on your activity rather than on the view you had just inflated. Because the activity does not have fields with the IDs icon, text1 or text2 you're not getting any results back. When you try to set them it throws the exception.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I've edited my comment with the solution to your problem! The null pointer exception made that easier to diagnose, thanks for adding the error log!

Comment: thank you , i add view before findViewById , but get this error : Error:(54, 48) error: non-static method findViewById(int) cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Oh. Oops I wrote view instead of row. Try again with the code I just edited and put up there. The issue was I wrote view.findViewById when it should've been row.findViewById. My bad!

Comment: Awesome! Good luck in the future!